# Failed Android build - unable to find Guava repository

Tags: android, gradle, build, repository, guava

I'm trying to compile an Android app and the Gradle build is failing. The project is in Java but does have Room code as well, which I believe is where the issue is arising from. The build is unable to find the Guava repository at [www.google.com:guava:23.6-Android](http://www.google.com:guava:23.6-Android) even though this file has been added as a dependency.

The initial result build fail looks like this:

```
Could not find com.google.guava:guava:23.6-android.
Required by:
project :App
```

The project-level build file:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    google()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

}

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
}
```

}

```
task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
```

}

The app level build file contains the following:

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
```

}

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 31
buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.nathan.digipizza"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 31
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

buildFeatures {
    dataBinding true
}
```

}

```
dependencies {

implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:26.3-android'
def room_version =  "2.3.0"
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0-rc01'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.1'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0-alpha05'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.4.0'
implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.3.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
annotationProcessor 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.3.0'
```

}

It is difficult to post the entire dependency tree since I'm still unable to post screen images. But the repository in question, com.google.guava:guava:23.6-android, is not listed as a dependency for any other files, and its entry in the tree for the release variant reflects this fact as it is situated furthest left on the tree as follows:

```
+--- com.google.guava:guava:23.6-android FAILED
```

This repository only appears once in the dependency tree, furthermost to the left.

The com.google.guava:guava:23.6-android repository has an updated version to 30.1-android. I did update the version, but the error remains and everything is the same as above except version 30.1-android replaces version 23.6-android.

I need to figure out how to resolve the build error, which I'll post here again for ease of use:

```
Could not find com.google.guava:guava:23.6-android.
Required by:
project :app
```

I don't understand how the build is failing to see this repository when it has been added as a dependency, and there doesn't appear to be any complications apparent by analyzing the dependency tree.

Comment: The ease of use error is different from the one above , its 23.6-android , and at the begin of the question its 30.1-android , so which one is correct ?

Comment: The initial error occurred using 23.6-android, and I have changed my post to reflect that. In fact, the initial error output was as follows:     *************                                                         

Could not find com.google.guava:guava:23.6-android.
Required by:
project : androidx.room:room-guava:2.0.0
**************
However, since I changed the version to 30.1-android, the error message has remained as I have it in my post where the message indicates the 'Required By Project' as App.